# Chrome Browser: An extension to cover webpage ads with floating windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ads, floating

Website memberships often are required to remove ads, adblockers being ineffective.

Is there an adblocker app that is undetectable by websites?

Is there a way to use floating windows to cover ads, so no adlocker app is used?

Comment: While it's certainly technically possible to add a DOM element above something else, the ads consume CPU/memory/resources so just covering them isn't very useful, which is why extensions don't do it.

Comment: Use something like https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole